# firefox started constantly hesitating for several seconds on almost every action

Tags: firefox

Fresh installation - plugins disabled, no malware. Chromium runs without delays. Firefox on every other action, including typing every now and then - takes 3-5 second pauses, sometimes displays a running wheel when the delay is even longer. 
Started at certain point in time. De-installation/re-installation didn't cure. Running as a single process didn't cure. Latest version.

Any ideas what can be causing this, specifically for the Firefox?

Comment: Try asking your question on SuperUser. StackOverflow is for questions relating to programming and code.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to v67 - I remember reading some glitch has been removed in prior versions that might have been causing this behavior.

Also, another idea would be not to limit your cache to a very low space.

+1 to move this question to SuperUser.